# Change background color when div class changes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a nav that opens with a button click. When you click the button, the class of the div for the nav changes. I want to dim the background color of the body when the nav opens (and more eventually).
I can think of a few ways to do this but I'm not sure which would be the easiest or if they are possible.

Method 1:
Somehow changing the class/div of the body when the button is clicked. This would not be hard to do, if you could set a class to the body.

Method 2:
Using js to change the elements individually. This would be relatively easy but more code than might be needed.

Method 3:
I tried using `.closed > body,` but this method can only be used to change things on a level down (held within the parent). So, with this in mind, I tried using `.closed < body`but it still did not work. I have also seen ~ used so I tried that but still no result.

Any advice anyone can give would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Adding a class to the body is as simple as `document.body.className = 'foo'`. If you need to add and remove classes, there are plenty of examples of simple functions to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work given it's the first nav element.

```
var nav = document.getElementsByTagName('nav');
nav[0].addEventListener('click', function(e){
   var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
   body[0].style.backgroundColor = "some color value";
});
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('nav')` and [*document.body*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#dom-document-body) are less to type. ;-)

Comment: True! Legacy javascript and similar convention is what I was going for here.